# How to install NPM on Dreamhost shared

Tags: laravel, npm, nuxt.js, chat, dreamhost

## Fatal error in , line 0

## Check failed: reservation_.SetPermissions(protect_start, protect_size, permission).

#FailureMessage Object: 0x78686cd993b0

`1: 0xa889e1  \[node\]`
`2: 0x1a37055 V8_Fatal(char const\*, ...) \[node\]`
`3: 0xdc5b0f  \[node\]`
`4: 0xdc882d v8::internal::PagedSpace::SetReadAndExecutable() \[node\]`
`5: 0xd0b473 v8::internal::Isolate::Init(v8::internal::ReadOnlyDeserializer\*, v8::internal::StartupDeserializer\*) \[node\]`  
`6: 0x11033ce v8::internal::Snapshot::Initialize(v8::internal::Isolate\*) \[node\]`  
`7: 0xbbcedd v8::Isolate::Initialize(v8::Isolate\*, v8::Isolate::CreateParams const&) \[node\]` 
`8: 0xa5ce81 node::NodeMainInstance::NodeMainInstance(v8::Isolate::CreateParams\*, uv_loop_s\*,         node::MultiIsolatePlatform\*, std::vector\<std::string, std::allocator\<std::string\> \> const&, std::vector\<std::string, std::allocator\<std::string\> \> const&, std::vector\<unsigned long, std::allocator\<unsigned long\> \> const\*) \[node\]`
`9: 0x9eab64 node::Start(int, char\*\*) \[node\]`
`10: 0x6f8836e0ac87 \__libc_start_main \[/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6\]`
`11: 0x982005  \[node\]`
`

Illegal instruction
I took this kind og error
I want to install NPM on Dreamhost shared.

Comment: A [similar issue for vscode remote](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3201) seems to suggest running `setfattr -n user.pax.flags -v "mr" $(find $NVM_DIR -type f -iname "node" -o -iname "npm" -o -iname "npx")` though you may need to adjust `$NVM_DIR` to instead be the directory that node is installed in if not using NVM

Comment: I faced the same issue for NodeJS v16 on DreamHost and @apokryfos's comment helped me to fix problem. 

It's also described at DreamHost's documentation page:
`If so, you'll need to update the security controls on each newly downloaded binary file before it will work. Run the following command as your user after each new version you download`
 https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029083351-Installing-a-custom-version-of-NVM-and-Node-js

Answer (score 0):

DH do not support in certain context version 14+ of node...I had a similar issue, I choose to work with version 14.21.3 and it worked...

Comment: The version restriction is true, but not related to the question. The [comment about binary file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74255625/how-to-install-npm-on-dreamhost-shared#comment136022953_74255625) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

From the DreamHost Knowledge Base:

> If installing Nodejs as a user on a Shared or Dedicated Server, there may be an error that looks like this:
>
> ```
> # Fatal error in , line 0
> # Check failed: reservation_.SetPermissions(protect_start, protect_size, permission).
> #
> #
> #
> #FailureMessage Object: 0x3dfe93bb400
> ```
>
> If so, you'll need to update the security controls on each newly downloaded binary file before it will work. Run the following command as your user after each new version you download:
>
> `setfattr -n user.pax.flags -v "mr" $(find $NVM_DIR -type f -iname "node" -o -iname "npm" -o -iname "npx")`
>
> This will need to be done each time a new version is installed.

[Source](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029083351-Installing-a-custom-version-of-NVM-and-Node-js)